# Cocoa: rearrange subviews when parent view resizes

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have an NSView with a number of subviews (e.g. NSLabel). I want these subviews to be aligned in a row, but if the parent view doesn't have enough width, I want the subviews to be wrapped to the lower leftmost space - just like words in English text when the line cannot fit them all.

I thought it can be done with Auto Layout, but I can't make it work. When my simple window with two labels and simple horizontal constraints resizes, the labels just overlap each other. Instead, I need the rightmost label to "jump" to the lower leftmost position.

How can it be done? Should I keep researching the Auto Layout feature?

Comment: it would be easier to understand if you can show some pics / diagram

Comment: @AnoopVaidya He wants a responsive layout. When two views(side by side) cannot be accommodated in the parent view, it should be stacked one below the other.

Comment: @GoodSp33d: if thats the case, it cant be done. He need to redraw or create a new set of view and replace it with new view.

Comment: Yes, I dont think it can be done with only auto layout. Frame has to be shifted.